# Error While Attempting to Use Custom Events

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-events

I am trying to use the information from the [Passing-Data-between-Windows-Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17371/Passing-Data-between-Windows-Forms) white paper to write some custom events to pass information between forms.
Unfortunately, I keep getting a `NullReferenceException` when I attempt to raise the event.  Below is a scaled down version of the relevant code that I have currently attempted.
Can someone please have a look and let me know if I am missing something?
BTW, I am using DevExpress forms if that makes a difference.  I only included the class that is generating my custom event since that is where the code is failing.  On the line where the `NullReferenceException` occurs, I have verified that the item is not `null`.

```
// Class that generates custom event
public partial class DiscountItemControl : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraUserControl
{
    // Add a delegate
    public delegate void ItemInsertedEventHandler(object sender, ItemInsertedEventArgs e);

    // AddCustomerForm an event of the delegate type
    public event ItemInsertedEventHandler ItemInsertedEvent;

    public void SaveAndClose()
    {
        // setup event args
        ItemInsertedEventArgs args = new ItemInsertedEventArgs(currentDiscountItem);

        // ********** THIS THROWS NullReferenceException *********
        // raise the event to notify listeners
        ItemInsertedEvent(this, args);

        this.Dispose();
    }
}

// Event arguments for event
public class ItemInsertedEventArgs : System.EventArgs
{
    private Item item;

    public ItemInsertedEventArgs(Item item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Item InsertedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.item;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code   Message="Object reference not set to an instance of an object."   Source="PureService"   StackTrace:
at MarineService.Tests.DiscountItemControl.SaveAndClose(Boolean& result) in C:\Aaron\Dev\HIGH PRIORITY\ServiceModule\MarineService\ServiceModule\UtilityClasses\UserControls\Items\DiscountItemControl.cs:line 336
at MarineService.Tests.AddEditItemForm.btnSaveAndClose_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Aaron\Dev\HIGH PRIORITY\ServiceModule\MarineService\ServiceModule\AddEditItemForm.cs:line 326
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseButton.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseButton.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at DevExpress.Utils.Controls.ControlBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseControl.WndProc(Message& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)   InnerException:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any event handlers attached. Usually custom event code has a check for that:

```
ItemInsertedEventHandler handler = this.ItemInsertedEvent;
if(handler != null) handler(this, args);
```

You need to have some code somewhere that adds a handler, i.e.

```
MyObject.ItemInsertedEvent += myHandler;
```

EDIT: Jon Skeet is right about race condition issues, you should use the local variable like he suggests. I've changed my example to match.

Comment: Thanks, today is the first time that I have every attempted to write my own custom events.  I am attempting to fire events from one form that other forms can subscribe to.  The detail that I initially missed in the white paper above is that they use a factory to create instances of all the forms which is where the handlers are wired up.  Is the factory the best route to take to accomplish sending data between my forms?  I do not want to tightly couple the forms by passing references around in the constructors.

Comment: Without seeing your whole application it's hard to say what the best route is, but it sounds like you are right in avoiding passing form references around in constructors.

Answer (score 4):

Chances are you don't have any subscribers for the event. If that's the case, the delegate field which backs your event will have a null value. You should check for that, like this:

```
ItemInsertedEventHandler handler = ItemInsertedEvent;
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(this, args);
}
```

The reason for using a local variable is to avoid a race condition, where the last handler is removed *after* the check but before the invocation.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the event is `null` when you're calling it. You need to check if it's `null` beforehand:

```
if (ItemInsertedEvent != null) {
    ItemInsertedEvent(this, args);
}
```